# Fast-track to Clojure/Java bindings for the EFL

Tags: java, binding, clojure, java-native-interface, jna

I want to make Clojure/Java bindings for the [EFL](http://www.enlightenment.org/).  [JNA](https://github.com/Chouser/clojure-jna) appears to require a lot of explicit struct mapping (Bridj does the same thing).  JNI has Gluegen, so I thought that might be simpler.

Going with Gluegen & deciding the Elementary module would be a good place to start, I ran:

java -jar /usr/share/java/gluegen2.jar -I. $(pkg-config elementary --cflags) /usr/include/elementary-0/Elementary.h

...and quickly found I'd need to create a ton of header stubs ie > 29

I've got three questions:

1. What's the fastest and easiest way to generate Java bindings for this project?
2. If Gluegen, is there a program for generating salient header stubs?
3. If JNA, is there a program for generating salient Pointer/Struct mappings?

Quick followup.  It does appear that I can do some things out of the box with clojure-jna

```
user=> (use 'net.n01se.clojure-jna)
nil
user=> (jna-invoke Integer eina/eina_init)
1
user=> (jna-invoke String eina/eina_str_escape "They'll start going ripe on us pretty soon.")
"They\\'ll\\ start\\ going\\ ripe\\ on\\ us\\ pretty\\ soon."
user=> (vec (jna-invoke (class (into-array String [])) eina/eina_str_split "Calvin;Leoben;D'anna;Simon;Dora2;105Rl;Six;Daniel;Sharon" ";" 0))
["Calvin" "Leoben" "D'anna" "Simon" "Dora2" "105Rl" "Six" "Daniel" "Sharon"]
user=> (jna-invoke Integer eina/eina_shutdown)
0
```

Answer (score 1):

[JNAerator](http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/) will generate bindings for you, for both JNA and Bridj.